# Rotating sky in latest version of A-Frame

Tags: aframe

Can anybody help me convert code from 0.8.2 to what the latest version of A-Frame requires?  The following code worked fine in 0.8.2 to rotate the sky, but I can't figure out how to get it to continue working with the latest A-Frame version.  I need other features from the latest version that do not work in 0.8.2, thus the need to update.

My working code:

```html
> <a-sky
> src="https://cdn.glitch.com/913639bf-0f9d-4623-94ee-35cb7bec54f5%2FHempsterFront.jpg?v=1616790774923">
> <a-animation attribute="rotation" fill="forwards" easing="linear"
> dur="18000" to="0 360 0" repeat="indefinite"></a-animation>   </a-sky>
```

Updated code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite it as an entity attribute **animation**. Take a look at A-Frame [Animation](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/components/animation.html) documentation

#### Working example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <a-scene>
      <a-sky src="https://cdn.glitch.com/913639bf-0f9d-4623-94ee-35cb7bec54f5%2FHempsterFront.jpg?v=1616790774923"
             animation="property: rotation; to: 0 360 0; loop: true; dur: 18000; easing: linear">
      </a-sky>
    </a-scene>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes - thanks Piotr.  I had kind of stumbled into that yesterday before I saw your answer today.  Not much difference in it really, but doesn't take much for it to not work, ha.  Thanks again.

Comment: May I kindly ask you to accept my answer? It will be helpful for other people who stumble across the same issue.